# Area ratio in a parallelogram

Tags: geometry

Let $ABCD$ be a parallelogram, and let $M$ and $N$ be the midpoints of $BC$ and $CD$, respectively. Let $P$and $Q$ be the intersections of $BD$ with $AM$ and $AN$, respectively. Then find the ratio of the area of quadrilateral $MNQP$ to the area of parallelogram $ABCD$. How do I find the ratio $AQ/QN$, else everything I have figured out.

Comment: And what is P, huh?

Answer (score 1):

Let the intersection of the diagonals of the parallelogram be $O.$

Then,  $\text{Area}(ΔCOQ) = \text{Area}(ΔAOQ) = \alpha.$

Also, $\text{Area}(ΔNQC) = \text{Area}(ΔDQN)= \beta.$

$\text{Area}(ΔAQD) = \frac{\text{Area}(ABCD)}{4} - \beta.$

$\text{Area}(ΔAOD) = \frac{\text{Area}(ABCD)}{4}= \frac{\text{Area}(ABCD)}{4} - \beta+ \alpha. $

Therefore $\alpha=\beta.$

We can then conclude $\frac{AQ}{QN} = 2$

Comment: Can you tell how you figured out the last step? "We can then conclude AQ/QN = 2"

Comment: @StavAlfi - because if α=β, then Area(ΔAQC)  =2α and Area(ΔNQC) = β = α. So Area(ΔAQC)  =2 *Area(ΔNQC), but ΔAQC and ΔNQC have the same height, so the base of ΔAQC (which is AQ) must be twice the base of ΔNQC (which is QN)

Answer (score 0):

$\triangle DQN\sim \triangle BQA$ by $AAA$ similarity property, so $\frac{AQ}{QN}=\frac{AB}{DN}=2$.